# C# String Splitting - No ending delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

My original question was answered yesterday about how to split out specific characters out of a string then delete what was between those two characters.

I talked about deleting from a string like this...

```
lg-109-1.ea-091-2.hd-180-1.hr-220-1
```

I didnt realise that sometimes my characters i wanted to split out (In this instance it was everything between hd and the . and hr and the .)

But you see for hr there is no `.` so it isnt being removed

This is the code im using...

```
public static string RemoveB(string s) {
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"hr.*?\.", "");
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"hd.*?\.", "");
    return s;
}
```

Does anyone know how to check if after the hr there is a ., and if there isnt then just remove it?

Comment: Just use an optional quantifier `?` to match 0 or 1 `.`: - `@"hr.*?\.?"`

Comment: I ready your question 3 times and still don't know what you want. does it immediatly after the `hr` or not . youll have to be more specific

Comment: s = Regex.Replace(s, @"hr.*?[.|$]", "");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"(hr|hd).*?(\.|$)", "");
```

`$` depicts end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Try using `(\.|$)` instead of just `\.` in order to match either `.` or the end of the line. Or if you know that hr is always the last entry, you can just use `$` instead of `\.` to always match the end of the line.

Answer (score -3):

```
public static string RemoveB(string s) {
    s = s.Replace("hr.","$");
    s = s.Replace("hr","");
    s = s.Replace("$","hr.");
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Ardhian..how does what you have written work..? can you explain.. it returns this when I run your code it returns 
`lg-109-1.ea-091-2.hd-180-1.-220-1` I would suggest running code in the debugger on your end or understanding what the OP wants before posting an answer that obviously doesn't work..

Comment: This is so long away from working its not even close. See your first and last replace. First you replace *hr.* with *$*. Then you replace *$* back to *hr.* giving you the **exact same result as you started with**. So the only thing you do here is replace *hr* with an empty string, and that is not what the op asked for at all. Therefore: -3

Comment: @Ardhian'koponk'Nugroho i didnt downvote you but your solution would not work..op wants to replace everything between `hr` or `hd` and `.`..your solution doesnt do that..even if it were java..it wont work